# php code to select and echo image from database in codeignitter

Tags: codeigniter

In my table, filename is the name of field in which i am inserting photo name from form.

Data in table like below..

id , filename

1     Chrysanthemum.jpg

**my uploads folder is placed in root direcory.**

for ex - C:\wamp\www\codeigniter_testapp

Inside this path my all folder are in below structure..

application

system

assets

uploads

user_guide

images names are inserting successfully in tables and also moving in uploads folder.

**But when i try to select them and display in my view..it shows blank image icon.**

plz help me to echo image in my view.

**controller code**

```
public function index()
    {           
        $this->select();                
    }           

    public function select()
    {           
        $data['results'] = $this->news_list_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('list_news',$data);
    }
```

**model code**

```
public function getAll()
    {       
        $query = $this->db->get('news_tbl');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**view code**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Headline</th>   
            <th>Story</th>  
            <th>Author</th> 
            <th>Photo</th>          
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>

        </tr>

     <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->cat_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->city_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->headline; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->story; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->author; ?></td>    

        <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->filename); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt=""/></td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Check short tags open or not in php.ini file

Comment: yes it is open but i also try to echo from long php tags..............but wont work in my table......

Comment: Check by inspect element and then check path of image.

Comment: i try to inspect element ......this shows below url http://localhost/codeigniter_testapp/news_list/%3C?=base_url(%27uploads/%27%20.%20$row[%27filename%27]);%20?%3E                                      how i correct this........

Comment: What is the url of the image when you inspect?

Comment: why news_list is coming? Also check your base_url.

Comment: Your image path should be like this-  localhost/codeigniter_testapp/uploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg

Comment: try to debug by inspect element check the path there

Comment: now inspect element shows proper url http://localhost/codeigniter_testapp/uploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg........nut img is displaying blank.....

Comment: image name is OK ? is it displaying right name of image?

Comment: yes ...this is right name.....and the name is also present in database....and image is also exist inside folder...

Comment: Just  print your result print_r($results); and check image is coming or not. If coming then check your uploads folder

Comment: OK try this <img src = "<?php echo base_url('uploads').'/'.$row->filename; ?>">

Comment: yes image is also  coming in $result........Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 47 [user_id] => raj [cat_id] => 22 [city_id] => 6 [headline] => good bye nagpur [story] => [author] => good bye nagpur [photo] => C:/wamp/www/codeigniter_testapp/uploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg [thumb_photo] => [filename] => Chrysanthemum.jpg [news_date] => 2015-11-10 18:44:17 [created] => 2015-11-17 13:14:29 [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 )

Comment: deep parekh........<img src = "<?php echo base_url('uploads').'/'.$row->filename; ?>">  this is not working i tried this.......as well

Comment: this is my $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter_testapp/'; in config.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I use to render images, you can try it:

```
public function images( $image_filename)
{
    $base_path = $this->config->item('images');
    $path = $base_path;
    $details = @getimagesize($path . '/' .  basename($image_filename));
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('Content-Type: ' . $details['mime']);
    @readfile($path . '/'  . $image_filename);
    exit();

}
```

In the src attribute, you will pass the path as a typical codeigniter url:

`http:/.some.com/controller/images/image_filename`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->filename); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt=""/>
```

Comment: sorry this line is also not working........but displaying image path correctly........i dont know whats the problem....in my code.....

Comment: this is my $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter_testapp/'; in config.....

Comment: please copy image path and open in browser new tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using base_url() function, make sure URL Helper is being loaded.
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html